# Modify Selection Parameters Rewrite Result in txt

Tags: python, python-2.7, text, parameters, cpu-word

I made a code that displays the sentences of a document and dump to a file the sentences that contain more than N occurrences of a certain POS, in which only one parameter is used as selection in the code example I am only taking sentences with more than 5 verbs .

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import os
import nlpnet
import codecs

TAGGER = nlpnet.POSTagger('pos-pt', language='pt')

def is_worth_saving(text, pos, pos_count):
     os_words = [word for sentence in TAGGER.tag(text)
             for word in sentence
             if word[1] == pos]
return len(pos_words) >= pos_count

with codecs.open('File_with_phrases.txt', encoding='utf8') as original_file:
with codecs.open('new_file.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    for text in original_file:
        #Example of a parameter with more than 5 verbs
        if is_worth_saving(text, 'V', 5 ):
            output_file.write(text.encode('utf8') + os.linesep)
```

This method counts only one grammar class. I wanted to expand so that the codic tells any of the open classes whether it's noun, adjectives, adverbs, verbs. If you have n occurrences in a sentence be it noun, adjectives, adverbs, verbs not to limit to just one grammatical class.
I thought of something like that, However you can not add.:

```
if(word.tag == Substantivo || word.tag == Adjetivo || word.tag == Advérbio || word.tag ==  Verbo)
NumberofWordsClass++;
if(NumberofWordsClass >= 5)
```

Comment: I understand you to mean that you want to retain sentences that contain five nouns or five verbs or five adjectives or five adverbs. Is that correct?

Comment: Actually I want phrases that have 5 words of this grammatical class. No matter what the class may be 2 verbs, 1 adjective and 2 nouns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the code should be like this.

I assume that `TAGGER` returns one sentence at a time. I don't know what tags it uses, so you'll have to replace the list I used with what you actually want in the statement, `if is_worth_saving(text, ['V', 'ADJ', 'ADV', 'N'], 5 )`.

Two code changes: (1) the statement I've just indicated, and (2) the list comprehension in the function definition.

```
import os
import nlpnet
import codecs

TAGGER = nlpnet.POSTagger('pos-pt', language='pt')

def is_worth_saving(text, pos, pos_count):
    os_words = \
        [word[1] for word in [sentence for sentence in TAGGER.tag(text)] if word[1] in pos]
    return len(pos_words) >= pos_count

with codecs.open('File_with_phrases.txt', encoding='utf8') as original_file:
    with codecs.open('new_file.txt', 'w') as output_file:
        for text in original_file:
            if is_worth_saving(text, ['V', 'ADJ', 'ADV', 'N'], 5 ):
                output_file.write(text.encode('utf8') + os.linesep)
```

Edit: I've put myself at a disadvantage because I haven't installed nlpnet and I don't know what's wrong. I did find one additional requirement though. The code must be able to deal with the fact that nlpnet can assign more than one part of speech to a single word. I think this code does that. I have also left in some debugging print statements.

```
import os
import nlpnet
import codecs

TAGGER = nlpnet.POSTagger('pos-pt', language='pt')

def is_worth_saving(text, pos, pos_count):

    pos_words = 0
    for sentence in TAGGER.tag(text):
        print(sentence)
        for word in sentence:
            print (word)
            pos_words += 1 if set(word[1].split('+')).intersection(set(pos)) else 0

    return pos_words >= pos_count

with codecs.open('File_with_phrases.txt', encoding='utf8') as original_file:
    with codecs.open('new_file.txt', 'w') as output_file:
        for text in original_file:
            if is_worth_saving(text, ['V', 'ADJ', 'ADV', 'N'], 5 ):
                output_file.write(text.encode('utf8') + os.linesep)
```

Comment: I understood the idea, however the code presents the following error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Class Word/Classificador.py", line 25, in <module>
    if is_worth_saving(text, ['V', 'ADJ', 'ADV', 'N'], 5 ):
  File "D:/Class Word/Classificador.py", line 13, in is_worth_saving
    [word[1] for word in [sentence for sentence in TAGGER.tag(text)] if word[1] in pos]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: I looked through nlpnet's source, the result of the tagger consists of nested collections of text > sentence > word. Something like [[(word1, pos1), (word2, pos2)], [(word3, pos1), (word4, pos2)]] for a two-sentences text.

Comment: I'm hoping that TAGGER.tag is an iterator. Would you please alter the script by putting `print (list(TAGGER.tag(text)))` immediately after `def is_worth_saving(text, pos, pos_count)` so that we can see what this thing is giving us? (And send us what it shows.)

Comment: Print Result: :
`[[(u'Do', u'PREP+ART'), (u'contrario', u'N'), (u',', u'PU'), (u'crime', u'N'), (u'de', u'PREP'), (u'infantic\xeddio', u'N'), (u'!', u'PU')]]`

Comment: Please see edit. If you could give me the text sentence that fails that might prove helpful.

Comment: What parameters you should change to pick up only words with 'x' grammar class?

Comment: Answering this would the same as answering your new question, correct?

Comment: Yes, I asked a new question for that doubt with an algorithm that you helped me to develop. @Bill Bell